# Adjust foreign keys with table migration

Tags: php, mysql, data-migration

I have several database tables that I'm consolidated into one, but need to update the foreign key reference to the new record being created:

```
name: parent_old
id | name  | ...
--------------------
1  | test1 | ...
2  | test2 | ...
3  | test3 | ...

name: parent_migrated
id | name  | ...
--------------------
22 | test1 | ...
23 | test2 | ...
24 | test3 | ...

name: child
id | fk | date | ...
--------------------
1  | 1  | 2016...
2  | 2  | 2016...
```

Given the above tables, the 'parent_old' is the original table that had its records migrated to 'parent_migrated' and as you can see the 'id' values of the respective records have been updated upon the migration.  I need to update the foreign key (fk column) reference in the 'child' table to the new values in the 'parent_migrated' table.  Can I do this with something like:

```
INSERT INTO parent_migrated (name,...) SELECT name,... FROM parent_old
```

or do I need to make this a multi-call approach?

Thanks!

Comment: multi-call would be safer. you can't get individual IDs if you're doing a bulk migration, and you'd need those to update the link records.  and since you can't have an "on update" cascade in this situation, there's no way to get the DB to do the update for you automatically.

Comment: just thinking, maybe if you use a trigger while migrating could do the trick. not sure though

Comment: @nassim could you show an example?